# How to resize the widget at the bottom of the screen in the gridstack.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, gridstack

As i'm using gridstack.js http://gridstackjs.com/ . As i'm facing a problem when resizing the widget at the bottom of the screen. That is scroll is not moving and resize has been blocked. 
Can any one suggest me any workaround method to resize the widget.

Answer (score 1):

If you looking on the docs (https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/blob/develop/doc/README.md#options) you'll find the draggable option, if you alter the "scroll:false" to "scroll:true" that should allow for dragging to automatically scroll when you drag the widget off the page.